# How to check not in array element

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am trying to check if an element is not in array than want to redirect page:
My code is as below:

```
$id = $access_data['Privilege']['id']; 

if(!in_array($id,$user_access_arr))
{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access Denied! You are not eligible to access this.'), 'flash_custom_success');
    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Dashboard','action'=>'index'));
}
```

I am confused how to check if element is not in array.
As we can check element exist or not in array using `in_array` function of PHP.
I am trying to check it using `(!in_array)` but I did not got result.

Comment: Can you post the values of `$id` & `$user_access_arr` ?

Comment: $id = 31; $user_access_arr = ([0] => 4,[1] => 8,[2] => 12,[3] => 31)

Comment: So as you can see `31` value exist in your array. So in_array will return true.

Comment: `if(!in_array($id,$user_access_arr))` not working in this case because you already have the value of id in your `$user_access_arr` array

Comment: $id = 31; $user_access_arr = ([0] => 4,[1] => 8,[2] => 12) if array value is like this than what will be the result

Answer (score 106):

Simply

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (!in_array("BB", $os)) {
    echo "BB is not found";
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I prefer this

```
if(in_array($id,$user_access_arr) == false)
```

respective

```
if (in_array(search_value, array) == false) 
// value is not in array
```

Comment: What is for OP?

Comment: Excuse me, that's the original poster so in this case the person asking a question. It helps if answers are explained.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yeah, but more than answer for OP are answers here for people searching similar problems, I guess. > How to check not in array element in php

Answer (score 7):

```
if (in_array($id,$user_access_arr)==0)
{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access Denied! You are not eligible to access this.'), 'flash_custom_success');
    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Dashboard','action'=>'index'));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$id = $access_data['Privilege']['id']; 

if(!in_array($id,$user_access_arr));
    $user_access_arr[] = $id;
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access Denied! You are not eligible to access this.'), 'flash_custom_success');
    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Dashboard','action'=>'index'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) method

```
$id = $access_data['Privilege']['id']; 

if(count(array_intersect($id,$user_access_arr)) == 0){

$this->Session->setFlash(__('Access Denied! You are not eligible to access this.'), 'flash_custom_success');
return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Dashboard','action'=>'index'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think everything that you need is **array_key_exists**:

```
if (!array_key_exists('id', $access_data['Privilege'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access Denied! You are not eligible to access this.'), 'flash_custom_success');
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Dashboard', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1 = "Orange";
$array2 = array("Apple","Grapes","Orange","Pineapple");
if(in_array($array1,$array2)){
    echo $array1.' exists in array2';
}else{
    echo $array1.'does not exists in array2';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can check using php in_array() built in function

```
<?php
  $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
  if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
 }
 if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
  echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

and you can also check using this

```
<?php
  $search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
  if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
   }
   ?>
```

in_array() is fine if you're only checking but if you need to check that a value exists and return the associated key, array_search is a better option.

```
$data = array(
0 => 'Key1',
1 => 'Key2'
);

$key = array_search('Key2', $data);

if ($key) {
 echo 'Key is ' . $key;
} else {
 echo 'Key not found';
}
```

for more details
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
0 => 'Key1',
1 => 'Key2'
);

$key = array_search('Key2', $data);

if ($key) {
 echo 'Key is ' . $key;
} else {
 echo 'Key not found';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.